# How to make the DecentExposure gem work on mailers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to include the Decent Exposure `expose` method in a Ruby on Rails mailer but I keep getting this error:
    NoMethodError - undefined method params' for #

I understand that the gem is looking for the controller params, which are not available in ActionMailer. However, their documentation says it works with mailers.

My code is very similar to the one in their [documentation](https://github.com/hashrocket/decent_exposure#rails-mailers):

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  expose(:user)

  def welcome_email(id:)
    mail(to: user.email, from: "...", subject: "...")
  end
end
```

I'm using Ruby 2.5.0, Rails 5.0.7.2 and DecentExposure 3.0.0

Comment: Are you sure that error has to do with the gem? Did you run bundle? Did you try restarting your server?

Comment: I can confirm I have run bundle and restarted the server. In the mailer, I have access to `users` if I `expose(:users, -> { User.last(10) })`. This is how I'm calling the mailer: `UserMailer.welcome_email(id: user.id).deliver_now`. This is the complete error message: `Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 300ms (ActiveRecord: 7.6ms) NoMethodError - undefined method `params' for #<UserMailer`. Thanks for your response!